# How to Count per Date in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, ms-reports

I have created a query using MSSQL and used that to create a report Using Report Builder.

I have the Dates in column which gives count as 5

```
Date and Time
-------------
2/11/2021
2/11/2021
2/11/2021
2/11/2021
2/12/2021
---------
5
```

I have Used Count function in Report builder level to give the count for this column as shown here:

[image: Count of Date]

For getting the count I used the Expression "=Count(Fields!date_and_time.Value)"

But I need to get the Count of Per date like below

```
Date and Time
-------------
2/11/2021
2/11/2021
2/11/2021
2/11/2021
---------
4
---------
2/12/2021
---------
1
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to format your data this way, but you can achieve this by adding a Row Group to your table, as the Parent Group of the Details.  Set this Row Group to group by the Date Value that you are displaying.

Having done this, you will get a set of Detail rows and a Sub-Total row for each distinct Date value.

Comment: Thankyou. I did the same as mentioned but this provides me the total count of the dates. I'm running a report for 2 days and want the Count for each day with regards to the dates. i.e., to know for each day how much entries has happened.

Comment: @RealGem  What I have just explain is how you get a subtotal per date, which is what you have asked for in your question.  Do what I have suggested here and add a screenshot of both your design view and rendered report to your question and we can see if this does what you need or where you are going wrong.

Comment: Please find the screenshot of Design view and rendered report. Suggest me with changes/modifications to achieve as requested. 
[Design view Image][1]
[Rendered report Image][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRHNq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSEHF.png

Comment: @RealGem  You need to have your total within the Date and Time group.  You currently only have a total for the entire table.  Add a row outside the Details group but within the Date and Time group which does the `count`